# Trying to fetch enum value for a dictionary

Tags: c#, enums

I have two enums

```
public enum Duration
{
    [Display(Name = "30 min")]
    ThirtyMinutes = 30,
    [Display(Name = "45 min")]
    FortyFiveMinutes = 45,
    [Display(Name = "60 min")]
    SixtyMinutes = 60,
    [Display(Name = "75 min")]
    SeventyFiveMinutes = 75,
    [Display(Name = "90 min")]
    NinetyMinutes = 90
}

public enum Price
{
    [Display(Name = "$8.95")]
    ThirtyMinutes = 895,
    [Display(Name = "$14.95")]
    FortyFiveMinutes = 1495,
    [Display(Name = "$19.95")]
    SixtyMinutes = 1495,
    [Display(Name = "$24.95")]
    SeventyFiveMinutes = 2495,
    [Display(Name = "$27.95")]
    NinetyMinutes = 2795
}
```

and I want to create a dictionary that has values like this

> (key, value) -> (duration int value, price int value)
>   ex. (30,895), (45,1495)

This is what I'm trying below but it only gets the duration int value for both

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> GetPriceDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach(var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Duration)))
        {
            var number = (int)value;
            var price = Enum.Parse(typeof(Price), number.ToString());
            dictionary.Add(number, (int)price);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

but this returns

> (30,30), (45,45), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to construct the Dictionary like you want, you need to use the enum value of `Duration` and not it's number

```
var price = Enum.Parse(typeof(Price), value.ToString());
```

After this change the Dictionary now looks like:

```
30:895
45:1495
60:1495
75:2495
90:2795
```

The test code I used, for reference:

```
var dictionary = GetPriceDictionary();
var keys = dictionary.Keys;
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{key}:{dictionary[key]}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each enum into the list and then use the `Zip` to create the dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> GetPriceDictionary()
{
    var duration = ((int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Duration))).ToList();
    var price = ((int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Price))).ToList();

    return  duration.Zip(price, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
}
```